# Hibernate - Key access

Tags: java, hibernate

I got one entity with a Key :

public class ParamGenerique implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/** Code type produit */
@Id
private ParamGeneriqueKey key;
```

In class ParamGeneriqueKey there's two column :

```
/** Champ type param. */
@Column(name="TYPE_PARAM")
private String typeParam = "";
/** Champ valeur param. */
@Column(name="VALEUR_PARAM")
private String valeurParam = "";
```

I try de make an update with hibernate :

```
Query lQuery = entityMgr.createQuery("UPDATE ParamGenerique p set p.libelleParam = :dest WHERE p.typeParam = :typeparam and p.valeurParam = :valeurparam");
lQuery.setParameter("dest", pDestinataire);
lQuery.setParameter("typeparam", "GESTION_MAIL");
lQuery.setParameter("valeurparam", "DESTINATAIRE");
```

But got an error telling me that typeParam is undefined in ParamGenerique.

Do you know how I can access this variable of my key in the request ? Something like p.key.typeParam maybe ?

Comment: do you have getter and setter method of your typeparam and valeurparam??

Comment: Hedley's answer works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the key, not the values it it holds

```
Query lQuery = entityMgr.createQuery("update ParamGenerique p set p.libelleParam = :dest where id = :key);
ParamGeneriqueKey key = new ParamGeneriqueKey();
key.setTypeParam("GESTION_MAIL");
key.setValeurParam("DESTINATAIRE");
lQuery.setParameter("dest", pDestinataire);
lQuery.setParameter("key", key);
```